# AWS Glue Limit data read from S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pyspark, aws-glue

I have a large bucket that contains more than 6M files.
I've run into this error `Failed to sanitize XML document destined for handler class` and i think this is the problem: https://github.com/lbroudoux/es-amazon-s3-river/issues/16

Is there a way I can limit how many files are read in the first runs?

This is what I have `DataSource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "s3-sat-dth-prd", table_name = "datahub_meraki_user_data", transformation_ctx = "DataSource0")`, can I tell it to read only a folder in my bucket? Every folder within is called like this: `partition=13/`, `partition=14/`, `partition=n/` and so on.

How can I work around this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, you can point to an S3 prefix to read files only from that.

```dynamic_frame.load(context=context, bucket="s3://my_bucket/my_prefix", transformation_ctx="my_job"
)```

Comment: @PraneethPeiris thanks, but I need some more info - I'm new to Glue and find it very clunky - how should I integrate what you wrote? Should I import something more than the default?

Comment: I will add it as an answer. Let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 2):

There are three main ways (as I know) to avoid this situation.

**1. Load from a prefix**

In order to load files from a specific path in AWS Glue, you can use the below syntax.

```
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame

dynamic_frame = context.create_dynamic_frame_from_options(
        "s3",
        {
            'paths': ['s3://my_bucket_1/my_prefix_1'],
            'recurse': True,
            'groupFiles': 'inPartition',
            'groupSize': '1073741824'
        },
        format='json',
        transformation_ctx='DataSource0'
    )
```

You can put multiple paths for `paths` and Glue will load from all of them.

**2. Use Glue Bookmarks.**

When you have millions of files in a bucket and you want to load only the new files (between the runs of your Glue job), you can enable Glue Bookmarks. It will keep track of the files it read in an internal index (which we don't have access to).
You can pass this as a parameter when you define the job.

```
  MyJob:
    Type: AWS::Glue::Job
    Properties:
      ...
      GlueVersion: 2.0
      Command:
        Name: glueetl
        PythonVersion: 3
        ...
      DefaultArguments: {
        "--job-bookmark-option": job-bookmark-enable,
        ...
```

This will enable bookmarks defined with the name used for `transformation_ctx` when you load data. Yes, it's confusing that AWS uses the same parameter for multiple purposes!

It's also important that you must not forget to add `job.commit()` at the end of your Glue script, where `job` is your `from awsglue.job import Job` instance.

Then, when you use the same `context.create_dynamic_frame_from_options()` function with your root prefix and the same `transformation_ctx`, it will only load the new files in the prefix in the hierarchy. It saves a lot of hassle for us in looking for new files. Read the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-continuations.html#monitor-continuations-implement) for more information on bookmarks.

**3. Avoid smaller file sizes.**

AWS Glue will take ages to load files if you have quite smaller files. So, if you can control the file size, then make the files at least 100MB in size. For instance, we were writing to S3 from a Firehose stream and we could adjust the buffer size to avoid smaller file sizes. This drastically increased the loading times for our Glue job.

I hope these tips will help you. And feel free to ask any questions if you need further clarification.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to control the # of files called a BoundedExecution. It's documented here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/bounded-execution.html

In the following examples you would be loading in 200 files at a time. Note you must enable Glue bookmarks for this to work correctly.

If you are using from_options it looks like this:

```
    DataSource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
        format_options={"withHeader": True, "separator": separator, "quoteChar": quoteChar},
        connection_type="s3",
        format="csv",
        connection_options={"paths": inputFilePath,
                            "boundedFiles": "200", "recurse": True},
        transformation_ctx="DataSource0"
    )
```

If you are using from_catalog it looks like this:

```
    DataSource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
        database = "database-name",
        table_name= "table-name",
        additional_options={"boundedFiles": "200"},
        transformation_ctx="DataSource0"
    )
```